# Keeping a row based on ranking

Tags: sql

I have a table like below. Basically different type of package of a different product with the input date. I want to keep those rows based on our preferences so that later I can filter out easily.  My ranking will be

1. UCC will be always top row (Latest input date)
2. UPC will be second (Latest input date)
3. But if there is more than UCC or UPC then we can keep those as 3rd
   or fourth row.

In shortly my sequence of ranking will be like
Latest UCC> Latest UPC> Old UCC> Old UPC

| Product No | Package Type | Length | Input Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | UPC | 10 | 12/09/2021 |
| 19 | UCC | 02 | 12/10/2022 |
| 19 | UCC | 05 | 11/08/2019 |
| 20 | UPC | 7 | 08/07/2022 |
| 20 | UPC | 6 | 07/09/2022 |
| 20 | UCC | 5 | 06/07/2018 |
| 21 | UPC | 7 | 06/07/2018 |

Basically I need look like this

| Product No | Package Type | Length | Input Date | Ranking |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | UCC | 02 | 12/10/2022 | 1 |
| 19 | UPC | 10 | 12/09/2021 | 2 |
| 19 | UCC | 05 | 11/08/2019 | 3 |
| 20 | UCC | 5 | 06/07/2018 | 1 |
| 20 | UPC | 7 | 08/07/2022 | 2 |
| 20 | UPC | 6 | 07/09/2022 | 3 |
| 21 | UPC | 7 | 06/07/2018 | 1 |

I tried with this to make a rank. But it doesn't work. May be there should be better way.

```
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER () OVER(
           PARTITION BY ProductNo
           ORDER     BY CASE WHEN PackageType = 'UCC' THEN 1
                             WHEN PackageType = 'UPC' THEN 2
                             ELSE 3 END ASC,
                        [Input Date] DESC ) as ranking
```

But it gave me look like this. Please look Product 19. It gave me Latest UCC> Old UCC> Latest UPC.

| Product No | Package Type | Length | Input Date | Ranking |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | UCC | 02 | 12/10/2022 | 1 |
| 19 | UCC | 05 | 11/08/2019 | 2 |
| 19 | UPC | 10 | 12/09/2021 | 3 |
| 20 | UCC | 5 | 06/07/2018 | 1 |
| 20 | UPC | 7 | 08/07/2022 | 2 |
| 20 | UPC | 6 | 07/09/2022 | 3 |
| 21 | UPC | 7 | 06/07/2018 | 1 |

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and rollback your question

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

One option is using the `ROW_NUMBER` window function twice:

- first time to detect your first values of "*UCC*" and "*UPC*" (partitioned by both "*ProductNo*" and "*packagetype*")
- second time to detect the ranking in your ProductNo rows, by ordering the first UCC and UPC values (thanks to first ranking)

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                  PARTITION BY ProductNo, PackageType 
                  ORDER     BY InputDate DESC         ) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                  PARTITION BY ProductNo 
                  ORDER BY rn, PackageType) AS Ranking
FROM cte
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9QmTt5MFvASHB91EoPHLEp/0)'s a demo in PostgreSQL, but should work in most DBMS' - given that your "*InputDate*" field contains DATE-typed values (and not strings).